# select columns according to column names in a list

Tags: python, linux, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a list of column names (in a text file) and the corresponding dataset (though I have a list with GT..., GT.... etc).
There are way too many columns in this list to write their names in a pandas command for example.

I would need to extract only the columns which names are in the list in my file...

[image]

Didn't manage to find a solution yet.....
(I tried awk 'NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {f[$i] = i})

Do you have an idea (I've already searched on SO for an answer but most of posts use a list of column names written in the command, but not from a file);
Many Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can easily do that using Pandas.

Comment: Have you tried df.columns?
If you need more specific help, paste some sample of your data

Comment: but in pandas i have to write the column names, don't you think ? I would like to use a list of column names in a file

Comment: so it just boils down to reading the file with the column names into a list then.  use that list to filter pandas.